# Next.js 13 Route Handler Hanging on GET Request

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm currently working on a Next.js 13 project and I'm having some trouble with the new routing feature. I've set up a route handler in `app/api/ingresos/route.ts` with the following code:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

export async function GET() {
  const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090');
  const records = await pb.collection('ingresos').getFullList({
    sort: '-created',
  });
  return NextResponse.json(records);
}
```

When I try to make a GET request to `http://localhost:3000/api/ingresos` using Thunder Client, the request just loads indefinitely and doesn't return a response. Additionally, I'm seeing a 404 error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/ingresos 404 (Not Found)
eval @ on-demand-entries-client.js:49
eval @ websocket.js:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js:57
```

I've checked that my PocketBase server is running and that the 'ingresos' collection exists. Here's the structure of my project:

```
PS C:\Users\zantl\OneDrive\Escritorio\REACT\gestions-gastospro> Get-Tree
app/
  api/
    Ingresos/
      route.ts
  components/
    navbar.tsx
    tablaIngresosCliente.tsx
  Ingresos/
    page.tsx
  favicon.ico
  globals.css
  layout.tsx
  page.tsx
pocketbase_0.16.10_windows_amd64/
  pb_data/
    data.db
    logs.db
  pb_migrations/
    1690143617_created_ingresos.js
    1690143631_updated_ingresos.js
  CHANGELOG.md
  LICENSE.md
  pocketbase.exe
public/
  next.svg
  vercel.svg
.eslintrc.json
.gitignore
next-env.d.ts
next.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
postcss.config.js
README.md
tailwind.config.js
tsconfig.json
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Could it be a problem with my async/await usage, or perhaps something to do with how I've set up my route handler? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run the code inside `try/catch` block and catch the error

```
export async function GET() {
  const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090');
  try {
    const records = await pb.collection('ingresos').getFullList({
      sort: '-created',
    });
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(records));
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return new Response('Could not fetch', { status: 500 })

  }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've implemented the try/catch block, but no errors are appearing in the console, which leads me to believe the issue might be with my routing setup. I've updated my original question with my project structure for reference. My route handler is in `app/api/ingresos/route.ts` and I'm trying to access it via `http://localhost:3000/api/ingresos`. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: you have typo. `Ingresos` directory is capital, should be lower case